# Android - modes of connectivity, device identification and device inter-communication?

Tags: android, connectivity

Can someone explain a couple of very simple concepts to me - I'm interested in mobile devices running android and how they are identified over networks. Some scenarios:

- **Device is connected over WiFi** - presumably the device has a standard IP address as with any host and can communicate with any other android host over TCP/IP (assuming it knows the participating device's IP?
- **Device is connected over bluetooth** - how are devices identified in this case?
- **Device is connected over mobile operator's network** - this is the one I'm interested in and confused by - is there anyway for two or more devices to discover each other and communicate via the mobile operator's network? How does a device communicate with a backend server in this scenario? In other words, how do apps and devices communicate when **not** connected to a WiFi network?

Thanks for any advice..

Answer (score 1):

I'm only sure about the bluetooth thing, so i only answer this part:

The Bluetooth interface on your device has an MAC adresse. So while communicationg over Bluetooth you can assume that this MAC adresse is a unique identifier for a specific device. You can also reach other devices by establishing a connection over this MAC adress- However, to get this mac adress in the first place, you have to know it from somwhere, or you have to search for other bluetooth devices in the reachabla area before.

Answer (score 1):

WiFi and 3g both attach the [mobile] device to the internet so it can make internet connections. 3G assigns a publicly addressable IP to the device, so one could, presumably open a server socket and listen for connections. The client would have to know the mobile IP, which may change quite frequently.

Bluetooth is more geared toward close-proximity. Devices in the vicinity can be connected to, after you have paired with them, which requires the cooperation of both devices which are to communicate.

If the goal is to produce an application which connects to nearby devices, I can think of the following ideas:

- 3g: all devices running the client register their position with a central database server. If the server detects that two clients are in close proximity, let them know so they can connect through the internet or through the server
- WiFi: you could use the same idea as 3g, or use broadcast/multicast packets to broadcast your presence. Other apps can listen for those broadcasts and discover which other devices are near.
- Bluetooth: A little trickier, as a device must be placed into discoverable mode in order for others to "see it". Discoverable mode is a temporary state and only lasts about 30 seconds (at a time).